# Can't get current playing on Spotify API

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'd like to use `spotify-web-api-node` to get the current track being played on Spotify. For some reason, the status code of res is 204, but `res.item` is null.

In this code, if Spotify's Access Token has expired, you can use refresh token to retrieve it again.

```
  const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    accessToken: SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    clientId: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: SPOTIFY_REFRESH_TOKEN,
  })

  let res = await spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack()

  if (res.statusCode === 401) {
    const api = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken()
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(api.body['access_token'])

    res = await spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack()
  }

  const currentPlaying = res.body.item
  console.log('currentPlaying', currentPlaying)
```

This is `res`.

```
    reqId: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
    body: null
    ip: "127.0.0.1"
    headers: {
      "host": "localhost:9292",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "max-age=0",
      "authorization": "[Redacted]",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "referer": "http://localhost:9292/admin/jobs",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "cookie": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
```

Comment: 204 is a Success No Content status code, so the call is succeeding, but pulls nothing. From doing some digging this is a known issue of that library. The github repo is also marked as Archived. Spotify has their own developer forum and this question pops up there too with no answers. If you can modify the call, try setting the Accept header to application/json.  https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hmm, I couldn't so I need to implement it on my own...